# consulta mongodb que devuelva los valores distintos a un valor predeterminado

Tags: mongodb, sql, distinct

Tengo el siguiente JSON en mongo y quiero realizar una consulta que me devuelva los objetos cuyo "channel" sea distinto a "SITE"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La siguiente sentencia:

```
db.getCollection('claimResponses').find({"admRfis.channel":"SITE"})
```

devuelve los que tienen channel: "SITE", ¿Cómo devolvería los que sean distinto a "SITE"?

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el operador [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) de comparación en Mongo, que establece lo siguiente: (traducción propia)

> `$ne` selecciona los documentos donde el valor del campo **field** no es igual al valor especificado. Esto incluye los documentos que no contengan el campo **field**.

Tu sentencia quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
db.getCollection('claimResponses').find({ "admRfis.channel": {$ne: "SITE"} })
```

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscas.